# Can't extract the data from the url repositories, but only the name of the title

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code block is responsible for handling a search form that accepts user input and fetches relevant papers from various online databases. Upon form submission, the code should first check if there is any user input, and if there isn't, it will exit. Otherwise, it will clear any previous search results and construct an array of objects representing the online databases to search, each containing a URL and a title.

For each repository, the code asynchronously fetches the HTML page and parses it to extract paper information such as title, authors, and summary. The exact parsing logic for each repository is provided in the code block. The information for each paper is displayed in a div element with class **`paper`**, which is then appended to a div element with class **`repository`** that corresponds to the searched repository.

This code block utilizes the **`addEventListener`** method to listen for a form submission event, and it utilizes the **`fetch`** method to make asynchronous HTTP requests to the various online databases. Additionally, it uses the **`querySelectorAll`** and **`querySelector`** methods to find specific HTML elements in the fetched pages and extract their contents. **Thank you in advance.**

```js
document
  .getElementById("search-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", async(event) => {
    console.log('submitted')
    event.preventDefault();

    const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input");
    const searchResults = document.getElementById("search-results");
    const query = searchInput.value.trim();

    if (query === "") {
      return;
    }

    searchResults.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous search results

    const repos = [{
        url: `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=${query}`,
        title: "NCBI PMC",
      },
      {
        url: `https://www.biorxiv.org/search/${query}`,
        title: "bioRxiv",
      },
      {
        url: `https://www.medrxiv.org/search/${query}`,
        title: "medRxiv",
      },
      {
        url: `https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}+filetype:pdf`,
        title: "PDF Search",
      },
    ];

    repos.forEach(async(repo) => {
      const repoDiv = document.createElement("div");
      repoDiv.className = "repository";
      repoDiv.innerHTML = `<h3>${repo.title}</h3>`;
      searchResults.appendChild(repoDiv);

      try {
        const response = await fetch(repo.url, {
          method: "GET",
          mode: "no-cors",
        });

        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(await response.text(), "text/html");

        // Add parsing logic for each repository here:
        // Extract paper information, like title, authors, and summary from the fetched HTML.

        // Example: For NCBI PMC, you can parse the search result items like this:
        if (repo.title === "NCBI PMC") {
          const paperItems = doc.querySelectorAll(".rprt");
          const topPaperItems = Array.from(paperItems).slice(0, 15);

          if (topPaperItems.length === 0) {
            repoDiv.innerHTML += "<p>No results found.</p>";
          } else {
            topPaperItems.forEach((paperItem) => {
              const paperDiv = document.createElement("div");
              paperDiv.className = "paper";

              const title = paperItem.querySelector(".title").innerText;
              const authors = Array.from(
                paperItem.querySelectorAll(".auths a")
              ).map((author) => author.innerText);
              const summary =
                paperItem.querySelector(".full-view-snippet").innerText;

              // Highlight exact title match
              if (title.toLowerCase() === query.toLowerCase()) {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4><mark>${title}</mark></h4>`;
              } else {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4>${title}</h4>`;
              }

              paperDiv.innerHTML += `
              <p>Author(s): ${authors.join(", ")}</p>
              <p>${summary}</p>
            `;
              repoDiv.appendChild(paperDiv);
            });
          }
        }

        //// Example: For bioRxiv: you can parse the search result items like this:
        if (repo.title === "bioRxiv") {
          const paperItems = doc.querySelectorAll(".search-result-item");
          const topPaperItems = Array.from(paperItems).slice(0, 15);

          if (topPaperItems.length === 0) {
            repoDiv.innerHTML += "<p>No results found.</p>";
          } else {
            topPaperItems.forEach((paperItem) => {
              const paperDiv = document.createElement("div");
              paperDiv.className = "paper";

              const title = paperItem.querySelector(
                ".highwire-cite-title"
              ).innerText;
              const authors = Array.from(
                paperItem.querySelectorAll(
                  ".highwire-citation-authors .highwire-citation-author"
                )
              ).map((author) => author.innerText);
              const summary = paperItem.querySelector(
                ".highwire-cite-snippet"
              ).innerText;

              // Highlight exact title match
              if (title.toLowerCase() === query.toLowerCase()) {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4><mark>${title}</mark></h4>`;
              } else {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4>${title}</h4>`;
              }

              paperDiv.innerHTML += `
              <p>Author(s): ${authors.join(", ")}</p>
              <p>${summary}</p>
            `;
              repoDiv.appendChild(paperDiv);
            });
          }
        }

        //  Example: For medRxiv: you can parse the search result items like this:
        if (repo.title === "medRxiv") {
          const paperItems = doc.querySelectorAll(".search-result-item");
          const topPaperItems = Array.from(paperItems).slice(0, 15);

          if (topPaperItems.length === 0) {
            repoDiv.innerHTML += "<p>No results found.</p>";
          } else {
            topPaperItems.forEach((paperItem) => {
              const paperDiv = document.createElement("div");
              paperDiv.className = "paper";

              const title = paperItem.querySelector(
                ".highwire-cite-title"
              ).innerText;
              const authors = Array.from(
                paperItem.querySelectorAll(
                  ".highwire-citation-authors .highwire-citation-author"
                )
              ).map((author) => author.innerText);
              const summary = paperItem.querySelector(
                ".highwire-cite-snippet"
              ).innerText;

              // Highlight exact title match
              if (title.toLowerCase() === query.toLowerCase()) {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4><mark>${title}</mark></h4>`;
              } else {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4>${title}</h4>`;
              }

              paperDiv.innerHTML += `
              <p>Author(s): ${authors.join(", ")}</p>
              <p>${summary}</p>
            `;
              repoDiv.appendChild(paperDiv);
            });
          }
        }

        // pdf search

        if (repo.title === "PDF Search") {
          const paperItems = doc.querySelectorAll(".g");
          const topPaperItems = Array.from(paperItems).slice(0, 15);

          if (topPaperItems.length === 0) {
            repoDiv.innerHTML += "<p>No results found.</p>";
          } else {
            topPaperItems.forEach((paperItem) => {
              const paperDiv = document.createElement("div");
              paperDiv.className = "paper";

              const titleLink = paperItem.querySelector(".r a");
              const title = titleLink.innerText;
              const url = titleLink.href;
              const summary = paperItem.querySelector(".st").innerText;
              const authorMatch = summary.match(/- .*? -/);
              const authors = authorMatch ?
                authorMatch[0].replace(/- /, "") :
                "";

              // Highlight exact title match
              if (title.toLowerCase() === query.toLowerCase()) {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4><mark>${title}</mark></h4>`;
              } else {
                paperDiv.innerHTML = `<h4>${title}</h4>`;
              }

              paperDiv.innerHTML += `
        <p>Author(s): ${authors}</p>
        <p>${summary}</p>
        <a href="${url}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">PDF Link</a>
      `;
              repoDiv.appendChild(paperDiv);
            });
          }
        }

        // Add parsing logic for other repositories similarly.
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching data from ${repo.title}:`, error);
        repoDiv.innerHTML +=
          "<p>An error occurred while fetching the data.</p>";
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
  <input type="text" id="search-input">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

Comment: It's unclear where exactly the problem is. Other that the subject you don't describe any errors, nor what the code is (not) doing and what you expect it (not) to do.

Comment: Are you using a jsfiddle or any online compiler for this code to execute?

Comment: Actually there is no error in the console, but can't extract the data from URL using DOM parse. The code responsibility is to fetch data from the URL response. when using " const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(await response.text(), "text/html");" No any data will display.

Comment: I am not using jsfiddle  or any other online compiler, just running on vscode